# StackDriver AWS Reduce Resource Usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

if I have an aws account with multiple ec2 instances (eg. Staging, Prod) but I would only like to monitor the production servers so that I won't be charged for monitoring everything, how would I go about doing this? I've tried to specify the specific instances in the policy however I get errors when selecting the list options.

Comment: Can you provide an example or a screenshot of the errors?

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the AWS role, you should be able to exclude specific resources from that role.  Stackdriver will see only what the role it's using has access to.